# ¿C++ no funciona bien?

Tags: c++, abogado-del-lenguaje

Hace años que no toco c++ y tengo mucho olvidado con lo que tal vez la duda que tengo o el posible fallo sea realmente algo básico en el lenguaje.

He escrito un pequeño código para probar la sobrecarga del operador delete en c++ con un destructor virtual y me he encontrado que solo funciona correctamente la primera vez que se llama a delete.

El código esta aquí (es una pagina que permite escribir código en linea y ejecutarlo, lo he probado en visual studio y gcc y pasa exactamente lo mismo): https://onlinegdb.com/SkiI1dNDQ

¿Alguien me podría indicar por que ocurre esto? Solo la primera vez funciona bien y la segunda ya no va bien

Pongo aquí el código también y el resultado que da:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { printf("~Base\r\n"); }
    void operator delete(void *m) { printf("delete Base\r\n"); }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() { x = 1; }
    ~Derived() { printf("~Derived\r\n"); }
    void operator delete(void *m) { printf("delete Derived\r\n"); }
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    Derived *derived = new Derived();
    printf("1) delete derived (%i)\r\n", ((Derived*)derived)->x);
    delete derived;
    printf("2) delete derived (%i)\r\n", ((Derived*)derived)->x);
    delete derived;
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
1) delete derived (1)
~Derived
~Base
delete Derived
2) delete derived (1)
~Base
delete Base
```

Ahora bien, si quitamos el "virtual" de la clase llamada "Base" todo va perfecto, lógicamente siempre que llamemos al delete con "Derived" (el codigo esta preparado para quitarle el virtual y no falle nada). Para ejecutarlo: https://onlinegdb.com/SkXkgdVP7

Gracias

Answer (score 7):

La pregunta "*¿C++ no funciona bien?*" tiene tanto sentido como preguntar "*¿El idioma español no funciona bien?*".

---

El lenguaje funciona, puede tener sus puntos a mejorar (por eso el estándar está en continua revisión) incluso sus fallos (por eso se recopilan defectos, que son estudiados por el comité de estándares) pero funcionar: funciona... si no: ni siquiera podrían escribirse compiladores ¿no?.

Tu código está invocando [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) pues estás usando objetos cuyo ciclo de vida ha finalizado, si consultamos [el estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) en el apartado 3.8 (traducción mía):

> #### 3.8 Tiempo de vida de los objetos
>
> [...]
>
> El tiempo de vida de un objeto `T` finaliza cuando:
>
> - (1.3) Si `T` es un objeto con un destructor no trivial (12.4), el destructor empieza, o
> - (1.4) el almacenamiento que el objeto ocupa es reusado o liberado.

Se puede ver en tu código que el destructor ha sido llamado, así que el tiempo de vida de tu objeto ha finalizado si no tiene destructor trivial (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 12.8 Destructores
>
> [...]
>
> **Un destructor es trivial si no es proveído por el usuario** y si:
>
> - (5.4) **el destructor no es virtual**,
> - (5.5) **todas las clases base directas de su clase tienen destructores triviales** y
> - (5.6) para todos los objetos miembro no estáticos de la clase que no sean de tipo clase (ergo formación), cada uno de ellos tenga destructor trivial.

Tu objeto tiene destructor definido y su clase base tiene destructor definido así que ni tu clase derivada ni tu clase base son triviales. Y es comportamiento indefinido porque (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 3.8 Tiempo de vida de los objetos
>
> [...]
>
> 5. [...] El programa tiene comportamiento indefinido si:
>
>    - (5.1) el objeto será o fue de una **clase con destructor no trivial y el puntero es usado como el operando de una *expresión-delete***

Usas el puntero a un objeto (con destructor no trivial) cuyo ciclo de vida ha finalizado en una expresión `delete`.

#### Conclusión

C++ no funciona mal, tiene unas normas que cuando no se siguen "*no se hace responsable de lo que pase*".

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. He estado probando en otros compiladores 
 y experimentando con destructores virtuales por defecto y cada uno se comporta de manera diferente, por ejemplo en visual studio un destructor declarado como virtual ~Base() = default; funciona perfectamente (como yo espero), pero en gcc se comporta como si el destructor tuviera cuerpo o no. Ahora bien, ¿existe la posibilidad de que un comportamiento indefinido pueda ser definido por el programador? Me gustaría hacer mas experimentos con c++.

Comment: También he visto que ahora la memoria se inicializa siempre a 0, me ha sorprendido mucho, ¿existe la posibilidad de evitar esto? Yo quiero tener el control de lo que hace el lenguaje y que no haga cosas por mi. Un ejemplo de esto ultimo: https://www.onlinegdb.com/BkbwgFrDX

Comment: Un destructor, aún marcado como `default` seguirá siendo un constructor definido por el usuario y la clase no dispondrá de un destructor trivial. Que diferentes compiladores se comporten de manera diferente frente al mismo código es una clara muestra de comportamiento indefinido. Es el estándar el que marca cuando un comportamiento es indefinido, el programador no tiene control alguno sobre ello.

Comment: El objeto `Test` inicializa a `0` sus sub-objetos porque así se lo has pedido al usar la [inicialización por valor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). En cambio [si no se lo pides](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/BkbwgFrDX) (usando la [inicialización por defecto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)) el contenido de los sub-objetos será indeterminado (incluyendo `0`).

Comment: Perdón, el enlace de ejemplo en que quería mostrar la diferencia entre inicialización por defecto e inicialización por valor [es este](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l2jnzNvXu1Y1CWhe) (no tengo cuenta en onlinegdb y no pude guardar cambios).

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, por lo que he leído si indica un constructor Test(){} que no hace nada tampoco me las inicializa

Comment: Esto se alarga mucho en los comentarios y es un tema suficientemente interesante como para hacer que desee sugerirte que abras una pregunta al respecto... de hecho no lo deseo ¡te lo sugiero!

Answer (score 4):

Como te han indicado en otra respuesta, es un *comportamiento indefinido*.

**No**, no liberas la memoria 2 veces; pero el trabajo de `delete` no es solo liberar memoria; **también es llamar al destructor**. Y eso **si** lo haces 2 veces.

Por experiencia, se que los compiladores hacen cosas *curiosas* al llamar a un destructor de una clase con funciones miembro virtuales: para ayudar al programador a descubrir errores, suelen modificar el puntero a la tabla de funciones virtuales (VTABLE), de forma que posteriores llamadas a funciones de esa instancia provoquen un error grave.

Eso es lo que está ocurriendo: la primera llamada a `delete` modifica el puntero a la VTABLE; la siguiente llamada, por decirlo de alguna forma, **no estás realmente llamando al destructor de `Base`, sino a otra cosa, que el compilador ha decidido** por tí**.

Eso explica porqué todo funciona bien al quitar el destructor `virtual`. Si la clase no tiene funciones virtuales (ni herencia virtual), no se usa un puntero a VTABLE; las llamadas a los destructores son *normales* (se limitan a ejecutar el código de usuario), y se muestran los mensajes que tu esperas.